# jQuery mobile pagecontainer load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What does this code do?

```js
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "#welcome2");
```

I have a jQuery UI autocomplete input box which I initialize, but it only works if any of the following is true:

- I call [load](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) on the fragment.
- The visitor starts on `#welcome2` (rather than coming from `#welcome1`)

I don't understand what [load](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) does or why I need it.

**EDIT:** Could it be something with the order in which jQuery UI and jQuery mobile are loaded?

**EDIT2:** It seems no widgets on not-loaded fragment are initialized.  I can't even do things like `.checkboxradio("disable")` unless the fragment has been explicitly loaded.  what does `load`ing mean and why isn't it done when the document is loaded?

Comment: [`pagecontainer()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/)

Comment: `load` is used to load external pages into DOM via Ajax. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/

Comment: But there's nothing external about the fragments.   Maybe i have a different definition of external.